# Button onClick triggering when modal opens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal with a button inside it in my application. That button triggers a function that opens a link in a new window with window.open(). My problem is that when the modal is opened it is triggering this function and opening a new tab. How can I prevent this

The modal structure from render:

```
if(this.props.displayModal){
            return(
                <div className="modBackdrop">
                    <div className="modal-fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabIndex="-1" id="companyModal">
                        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document"> 
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h3 className="modal-title">{readyForDisplay.fields.Company_Name}</h3>
                                    <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.onModalClick}>
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                    {this.constructModalBody(readyForDisplay)}
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.feedbackLink(readyForDisplay.fields.Company_Name)} id="feedbackButton">Update Profile</button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success ml-auto" style={{backgroundColor: '#07d585'}} onClick={this.onModalClick}>Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            );
        }else{
            return(null);
        }
```

The function called by onClick:

```
feedbackLink(prefill){


        let link = "removed for StackOverflow" + prefill
        window.open(link)
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `onClick` as a reference to function, you should not call a function on `onClick`

You can pass `onClick` as two ways

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick()}>Click Me!</button>
```

You are directly calling onClick function, it have to be changed to

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => {this.feedbackLink(readyForDisplay.fields.Company_Name)}} id="feedbackButton">Update Profile</button>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help..!!, Wish you all the best